# PySpark: Search For substrings in text and subset dataframe

Tags: string, search, pyspark, substring, subset

I am brand new to `pyspark` and want to translate my existing `pandas` / `python` code to `PySpark`.

I want to subset my `dataframe` so that only rows that contain specific key words I'm looking for in `'original_problem'` field is returned.

Below is the Python code I tried in PySpark:

```
def pilot_discrep(input_file):

    df = input_file 

    searchfor = ['cat', 'dog', 'frog', 'fleece']

    df = df[df['original_problem'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor))]

    return df
```

When I try to run the above, I get the following error:

> AnalysisException: u"Can't extract value from original_problem#207:
>   need struct type but got string;"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In pyspark, try this:

```py
df = df[df['original_problem'].rlike('|'.join(searchfor))]
```

Or equivalently:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.where(F.col('original_problem').rlike('|'.join(searchfor)))
```

Alternatively, you could go for `udf`:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

searchfor = ['cat', 'dog', 'frog', 'fleece']
check_udf = F.udf(lambda x: x if x in searchfor else 'Not_present')

df = df.withColumn('check_presence', check_udf(F.col('original_problem')))
df = df.filter(df.check_presence != 'Not_present').drop('check_presence')
```

But the DataFrame methods are preferred because they will be faster.

Comment: change like to `rlike`

Comment: @PineNuts0 look at the edited answer- [`pyspark.sql.Column.rlike()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.rlike) supports regular expression patterns.